# SophosLabs Intelix Roadmap

Tags: sophoslabs-intelix

Since there was no update on SophosLabs Intelix  in git hub  since Dec 2020, I like to check if there is a roadmap on the APIs.

Will it continue or there are some major changes?

Thx

Checked with github

Answer (score 1):

SophosLabs Intelix is being actively developed. The cloud platform provides analysis into the Sophos products (e.g. [Xstream protection](https://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/next-gen-firewall/features) for Firewall or Sophos E-mail advanced)

The APIs have been very stable, as you mention unchanged for over a year. The last update was to add additional functionality for web analysis.

The backend systems for Intelix are kept up to date with the latest tools and technologies from [SophosLabs and Sophos AI](https://www.sophos.com/en-us/labs/intelix). This means that the majority of the updates to the solution are in the detection capabilities that power the platform.

The combination of constantly updating detection technologies and stable APIs is great for people building integrations. You get the latest and best scanning technology without having to change your integration.

Comment: Thanks. It is good to hear from the product owner. We will try out the APIs.